# Chrome's Developer Tools open unmaximized after update, is there a way to make the window open Maximized again?

Tags: google-chrome, maximize, developer-tools

Is there a way to make the Developer Tools window open Maximized automatically again?

I've just updated Google Chrome (to version 17.0.963.56), and I realize when I open the Developer Tools, the window is not maximized anymore (I have 2 screens, and it automatically opened maximized on the second one before updating).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have filed a bug report for you: http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=115113

Answer (score 1):

Try

> Shift+Right-clicking it > Restore or Maximize.